# The work done by a thread (inside a child process) on a class object. When child exits the work done by thread on class object is deleted

Tags: c++, class, pthreads, fork, pthread-join

I have a simple class with a variable (var1). The function of the class "changeVar" will be passed to pthread which will update the value.
My question is when that thread is called inside a child and it updates the value after the child exits why does the value go back to the default which is 0.
And how can I keep the updated value in the parent process if there is a way to do so.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <iostream> 
#include <random> 
#include <ctime>
#include <sys/wait.h>

class my_class
{
public: 
    int var1;
    my_class()
    {
        var1 = 0; 
    }
    void* changeVar() //change variable function thread will start execution from this function
    {
        this->var1 = 1; //the thread will then update the value
    }
    void print_var() //function to simply print the var1 variabel.
    {
        std::cout << "The value of var 1 = " << this->var1 << std::endl; 
    }
};

int main()
{
    typedef void* (*THREADFUNCPTR) (void* ); 
    my_class* my_class_ptr = new my_class();  // creating pointer to class that I will send to the thread.

    //forking a child; 
    if(fork() == 0)
    {
        pthread_t thread; 
        pthread_create(&thread, NULL, (THREADFUNCPTR) &my_class::changeVar, my_class_ptr); //creating thread
        pthread_join(thread, NULL); 
        my_class_ptr->print_var(); //on this print call the value of var1 printed is 1
        exit(0);
    } 
    else
    {
        wait(NULL);
        
        my_class_ptr->print_var(); //on this print call the value of var1 is 0

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Parent and child processes are completely independent processes. The thread executes in the child process, and, as such, the parent process has no knowledge of it.

A `fork()` basically gives you an identical twin of the original process. That's your child process. At the point of the `fork()` they are identical twins, but they are completely independent processes.

The new process has its own memory, and its own `my_class_ptr`, that has nothing to do, whatsoever with the parent process.

So, when the child process terminates the parent process still has the same `my_class_ptr` that it did before the `fork()`. Nothing changed.

Additionally:

```
       pthread_create(&thread, NULL, (THREADFUNCPTR) &my_class::changeVar, my_class_ptr); //creating thread
```

This is technically undefined behavior. pthreads are not a part of the C++ standard. pthreads are an operating-system specific APIs that have no guarantees of C++ compatibility. A particular implementation might offer some kind of guarantees that invoking a class method, in this manner, via `pthread_create` might work, otherwise this is undefined behavior. You cannot expect any meaningful results in the child process either.

Proper C++ code uses C++'s `std::thread`, where a comparable invocation ***is*** defined behavior. You should reimplement this program using `std::thread`s, pretty much as is.

Comment: C++20 is shipped with `std::jthread`; dtor joins. I would use that one if available.

Comment: The point about undefined behavior might be clarified.  We don't ordinarily make that claim just because a call is made to a function that is not part of the C++ standard library.  What is undefined here is more to do with `my_class::changeVar` not having C linkage and not having the signature that `pthread_create()` expects.  The code seems to assume that these deficiencies will offset each other, and maybe they will, but *that's* where the undefined behavior comes in.